# Yeoman Angular-fullstack generator post error

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, mean-stack, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm using the **Angular-fullstack** generator to learn how Angular communicates with Mongoose. After running `grunt serve` without modifying any files, the **Sign up** form doesn't work giving a `POST 400 (Bad Request)`.

Where should I do the modifications to get `POST` create a new user in the database?

An [example](http://fica2014-luandro.rhcloud.com/signup) I uploaded to Openshift.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this is how I solved:

On file: /lib/controllers/users.js on the create function, change `req.body` and use `req.query` instead.

```
/**
 * Create user
 */
exports.create = function (req, res, next) {
  var newUser = new User(req.query);
  newUser.provider = 'local';

  newUser.save(function(err) {
    if (err) return res.json(400, err);

    req.logIn(newUser, function(err) {
      if (err) return next(err);

      return res.json(req.user.userInfo);
    });
  });
};
```

Regards